# What lateral and rotational accelerations can a spacecraft achieve?

Tags: acceleration, rcs

I've found information like the Space Shuttle Orbiter has so many thrusters each generating so much force to maneuver "with redundancy" in orbit. But without knowing something like how many thrusters are firing and their relative orientations, I don't know how to come up with a bottom-line number in m/s^2 or rad/s^2. Even approximate or typical values would be helpful.

Comment: The information you seek for rotational motion of the space shuttle is in the answer to this question: https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14560/how-fast-can-the-space-shuttle-change-its-attitude-in-space  It isn't a duplicate though because it doesn't address translational motion.

Comment: That helps a lot! I suppose it must be similar for other spacecraft, like Soyuz and Dragon, since they're meant to do similar things, like match orbits and dock with stuff?

Comment: @Greg The smaller spacecraft might do things a little faster than the shuttle (far and away the heaviest crewed spacecraft ever flown), but probably not much, because safety is paramount and there's usually no real hurry to maneuver.

Comment: I'm not doing highly serious research, anyway. More asking myself questions like "If a Space Shuttle and a Soyuz capsule dogfought in orbit..." So approximately 0.5 ft/s^2 is good enough, and the rest is orbital mechanics.

Answer (score 3):

I found transverse acceleration for the Space Shuttle Orbiter on page 1009 of the Shuttle Crew Operations Manual (December 15, 2008). I don't know how to reproduce the table here. But it depends on weight, of course. Also axis and direction. At 180,000 pounds (lightest weight in the table), max of 0.61 ft/s^2 in +X (noseward), apparently 0.32 in -X, 0.22 in +-Y (port and starboard), 1.29 in +Z (through the deck), 0.98 in -Z, and with the OMS 2.14 ft/s^2. Pretty darn soft acceleration. But if any maneuver could be done in minutes, to do it in seconds was considered a waste of fuel.

This older answer gives the rotational parameters: [How fast can the space shuttle change its attitude in space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/14560/how-fast-can-the-space-shuttle-change-its-attitude-in-space/14573#14573)

Comment: I added a link to the answer with the rotational parameters; that makes this a complete answer. Please rollback if the change is unwelcome. And welcome to Space SE!

Comment: @Greg it's always okay to accept your own answer. It's been a month your answer is well received, even by shuttle gurus, so I think you can click accept.